# Can I Register more than one shutdown function in PHP?

Tags: php

using `register_shutdown_function` I can register code to execute at the end of a PHP script execution "no matter what".

Can I have more than one function registered?

This question arises since I may not know if someone has already registered one when I'm about to register my own.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nevermind, the answer is yes.  Manual:

https://www.php.net/register_shutdown_function

Comment: FYI, someone figured out the order they are executed at shutdown (as well as the order of any __destruct methods defined), if that interests you: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php#76710

Answer (score 1):

Yes, each will be called in the order it was registered, per the [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/register_shutdown_function).